# how to return reference of a class in c++

Tags: c++, class, reference

As far as I know, `this` is a pointer and `*this` is a reference. So if I have a class `Sample` and a method of it like:

```
Sample operator++(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<this->length;i++){
        this->array[i]+=1;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Or another approach would be.

```
Sample &operator++(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<this->length;i++){
         this->array[i]+=1;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Between these two, which will be the correct approach?

Comment: The second is idiomatic You are implementing *prefix* `operator++`, which should return a reference to self.

Comment: Actually, `*this` is an lvalue `Sample`. No reference. You only get the reference when `*this` is bound to the eventual return value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one will use the copy constructor. I.e. you get a copy.

The second one will just return a reference. So only one object will exist and no copy will be made

Comment: in case you still doubt about the answer: the second one.